# Java Keylisteners and Key Bindings Speed Comparison

Tags: java, performance, comparison, key, keylistener

I'm currently working on a simple software synthesizer using the user's keyboard to control the pitch like a "piano."  Problem is, I'm using a key listener and a massive switch statement for every key code to get the frequency.  This is pretty excessive.  Key bindings fire when a specific key is pressed, and that seems like it should be faster than searching through tons of codes, but does it work any differently under the hood?  Efficiency is imperative since I'm wanting to run this on a pi.

Comment: Implement both approaches and benchmark.

Comment: Key bindings use a two stage look up mechanism to.  First the "action key" is looked up based on the key event (this is taken from a `Map`), then the "action key" is used to look up the associated `Action` and the action is fired.  The major over head is going to be the `Map` look ups.  Based on the complexity of your if statements, it would be balancing act to say which was faster.  The key bindings how ever are easier to update, manage and modifier - IMHO